# Can't upgrade Outdated Google ReCAPTCHA version 1 for ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

We are currently using reCAPTCHA version 1 and we're getting that error (reCAPTCHA V1 IS SHUTDOWN).

We're currently using the Recaptcha.dll (Product version 1.0.0.0) for ASP.Net.
How to update this to the current version. There's no newer version dll in their download page.

https://code.google.com/archive/p/recaptcha/downloads

We're currently using the the normal reCAPTCHA control inside of the  tag.

```
 <%@ Register TagPrefix="recaptcha" Namespace="Recaptcha" Assembly="Recaptcha" %>

<recaptcha:RecaptchaControl
ID="recaptcha"
runat="server"
PublicKey="your_public_key"
PrivateKey="your_private_key"
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of version 2 there is no bespoke Nuget package or library for asp.net webforms. You'd have to use the methods listed in the documentation and migrate to version 2, better v3.

So, go over to your admin panel at google, get the new library then all you have to do is add some html markup to your page:

```
<body>
    <form action="/" method="POST">
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"></div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
</body>
```

For v3 it looks like this:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"></script>
<script>
    grecaptcha.ready(function() {
    grecaptcha.execute('xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {
         ...
    });
});
</script>
```

Replace the data-sitekey property with your specific key and you should be up and running already.

Reference for v2: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display

Reference for v3: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3